# How to show the book details when clicking on a book

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a `snapshotData` variable which contains the field author which is used in a searched bar to find book. I then have a widget searchedData which displays a list of books based on the author:

```
 Widget searchedData() {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshotData.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onDoubleTap: () {
              Get.to(showBookDetails(),
                  transition: Transition.downToUp,
                  arguments: snapshotData.docs[index]);
            },
            child: ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              title: Text(
                snapshotData.docs[index]['Title'],
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 24.0),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                snapshotData.docs[index]['Author'],
                style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                    fontSize: 24.0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    }
```

when someone double taps on a book in the GestureDetector i want to show another page which should display the book details specificly from the tappped book:

```
 Widget showBookDetails() {
    return Scaffold(
      
  }
```

But when i double tap on a book i get error:

```
You are trying to use contextless navigation without
      a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
      If you are testing your app, you can use:
      [Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
      a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]
      for a [GetMaterialApp].
```

How can i make sure that when i tap on a book in searchedData, i can display the book details in the widget showBookDetails?

**EDIT**

So i resolved the error mentioned by changing MaterialApp with GetMaterialApp in the main.dart. So i will close this post as solved and ask another question regarding how i can display the book details when tapping on a book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Get.to for navigation, change MaterialApp widget with GetMaterialApp. Probably it's in main.dart file.

Comment: This helped the error and it shows the page but i still don't know how i can display the book details when tapping on a book

Comment: Declare a selected book variable in getx contoller using obs . Use it in book detail page. Your variable should be something like, var selectedBook = Book().obs; and your view should something like Obx(() => Container(child: Text(_controller.selectedBook.value.name))). Put your contoller in before navigation using Get.put(BookController()) and get it on detail page using BookController _controller = Get.find();